# Error:Closing modal: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- Login

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting the following error when opening my project:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- Login.
```

I have the `ui.boostrap` declared in the module file. I've updated the `ui-boostrap-tpls.js` and `AngularJS`.

The caller for my modal is:

```
   function showLogin() {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: vm.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
                    controller: 'Login',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    size: 'sm',
                    resolve: {

                        }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function (user) {
                vm.userName = user.userName;
            });
            //vm.showLogInForm = true;
        }
```

The login controller is:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'Login';
    angular.module('app')
        .controller(controllerId, Login);

    Login.$inject = ['common',  'loginResource', 'loginService',      '$uibModalInstance'];

    function Login(common, loginResource, loginService, $uibModalInstance ) {
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Log in';
        vm.user = {};
        vm.submit = submit;
        vm.cancel = cancel = cancel;
        vm.loginService = loginService;

        activate();

        function activate() {

            var promises = [];
            common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
                .then(function () {  });
         }

        function getLogin(username, password) {
            loginResource.query(function (data) {
               vm.sponsors = data;
           });

        }

        function submit() {
        //check login
            loginResource.get(
               { userName: vm.userName, password: vm.password },
              function (data) {
                   vm.user = data;
                   if (vm.user != null) {
                       vm.loginService.setLoggedIn = true;
                       vm.loginService.setUser(vm.user);
                   }
               });
            $uibModalInstance.close(vm.user);

        }

        function cancel() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Are you using the Login controller only for that modal, and not for any other view?